# Google Admob rewarded ad not working in android app

Tags: java, android, admob, admob-rewardedvideoad

I am trying to show a rewarded ad in Android Studio using Google Admob, and I have watched several different videos on it, but none of them work for me. When I run it and click the button that is supposed to show the ad, it doesn't work and gives me the log message:

```
I/Ads: ExoPlayerAdapter initialized.
W/Ads: Failed to preload url gcache://video/media/-438303185308675417?url=https%3A%2F%2Frr2---sn-nx57ynss.googlevideo.com%2Fvideoplayback%3Fexpire%3D1682760455%26ei%3Dh3JMZJzUJ4Ggn88P2ruSgAU%26ip%3D50.54.142.60%26id%3Df9ead5933fc112a7%26itag%3D22%26source%3Dyoutube%26requiressl%3Dyes%26mh%3DEA%26mm%3D31%26mn%3Dsn-nx57ynss%26ms%3Dau%26mv%3Dm%26mvi%3D2%26pl%3D17%26susc%3Dgvp%26acao%3Dyes%26ctier%3DL%26mime%3Dvideo%252Fmp4%26vprv%3D1%26dur%3D7.314%26lmt%3D1674261152906091%26mt%3D1682731265%26txp%3D1211224%26sparams%3Dexpire%252Cei%252Cip%252Cid%252Citag%252Csource%252Crequiressl%252Csusc%252Cacao%252Cctier%252Cmime%252Cvprv%252Cdur%252Clmt%26sig%3DAOq0QJ8wRgIhAMhoxD5nSzmnSw0L60WwzR5cGT4l_Wwuer1OOWtx9NAqAiEApLhRwq70X_-0NHQrCVTZVJc-E0s1ZohyT5oX0eJU734%253D%26lsparams%3Dmh%252Cmm%252Cmn%252Cms%252Cmv%252Cmvi%252Cpl%26lsig%3DAG3C_xAwRQIhAI3H1pNuJXiINj3EanAMFrdw6puD5Wv3V99L6kx7gSY7AiBF37wcJZar2usZk5U2tXDO6OEn0p_zAolLg06P-9FeNQ%253D%253D%26cpn%3D0b_QCAymqjqUzpzE%26ic%3Dgmasdk&tag.duration=7314&tag.check_url=https%3A%2F%2Frr2---sn-nx57ynss.googlevideo.com%2Fvideoplayback%3Fexpire%3D1682760455%26ei%3Dh3JMZJzUJ4Ggn88P2ruSgAU%26ip%3D50.54.142.60%26id%3Df9ead5933fc112a7%26itag%3D22%26source%3Dyoutube%26requiressl%3Dyes%26mh%3DEA%26mm%3D31%26mn%3Dsn-nx57ynss%26ms%3Dau%26mv%3Dm%26mvi%3D2%26pl%3D17%26susc%3Dgvp%26acao%3Dyes%26ctier%3DL%26mime%3Dvideo%2Fmp4%26vprv%3D1%26dur%3D7.314%26lmt%3D1674261152906091%26mt%3D1682731265%26txp%3D1211224%26sparams%3Dexpire%2Cei%2Cip%2Cid%2Citag%2Csource%2Crequiressl%2Csusc%2Cacao%2Cctier%2Cmime%2Cvprv%2Cdur%2Clmt%26sig%3DAOq0QJ8wRgIhAMhoxD5nSzmnSw0L60WwzR5cGT4l_Wwuer1OOWtx9NAqAiEApLhRwq70X_-0NHQrCVTZVJc-E0s1ZohyT5oX0eJU734%3D%26lsparams%3Dmh%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cmvi%2Cpl%26lsig%3DAG3C_xAwRQIhAI3H1pNuJXiINj3EanAMFrdw6puD5Wv3V99L6kx7gSY7AiBF37wcJZar2usZk5U2tXDO6OEn0p_zAolLg06P-9FeNQ%3D%3D%26cpn%3D0b_QCAymqjqUzpzE Exception: Player is accessed on the wrong thread.
    Current thread: 'AdWorker(Default) #17'
    Expected thread: 'main'
    See https://exoplayer.dev/issues/player-accessed-on-wrong-thread
I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.ads.dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.ads.dynamite:231004600
I/DynamiteModule: Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.ads.dynamite, version >= 231004600
I/RaffleActivity: onAdLoaded
V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
I/ViewRootImpl@16d0cf6[MainActivity]: ViewPostIme pointer 0
I/ViewRootImpl@16d0cf6[MainActivity]: ViewPostIme pointer 1
D/RaffleActivity: {
      "Code": 0,
      "Message": "Internal error.",
      "Domain": "com.google.android.gms.ads",
      "Cause": "null",
      "Response Info": {
        "Response ID": "h3JMZInhIcnAn88P7tizqAw",
        "Mediation Adapter Class Name": "",
        "Adapter Responses": [
          {
            "Adapter": "com.google.ads.mediation.admob.AdMobAdapter",
            "Latency": 60002,
            "Ad Source Name": "Reservation campaign",
            "Ad Source ID": "7068401028668408324",
            "Ad Source Instance Name": "[DO NOT EDIT] Publisher Test Video Campaign",
            "Ad Source Instance ID": "6877926149710223",
            "Credentials": {
              "pubid": "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544\/5224354917\/cak=no_cache&cadc=8e&caqid=h3JMZLGVIbjwtOUPhrmkcA",
              "campaign_id": "1057492276"
            },
            "Ad Error": {
              "Code": 0,
              "Message": "Internal error.",
              "Domain": "com.google.android.gms.ads",
              "Cause": "null"
            }
          }
        ],
        "Response Extras": {
          "mediation_group_name": "Campaign"
        }
      }
    }
I/Ads: Ad failed to load : 0
W/udios.RaffleAp: Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard;->close()V (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
I/ViewRootImpl@16d0cf6[MainActivity]: ViewPostIme pointer 0
I/ViewRootImpl@16d0cf6[MainActivity]: ViewPostIme pointer 1
I/udios.RaffleAp: Background concurrent copying GC freed 183395(6948KB) AllocSpace objects, 1(56KB) LOS objects, 49% free, 7415KB/14MB, paused 238us total 143.245ms
W/udios.RaffleAp: Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard;->warnIfOpen()V (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
```

Here is the code I used to load the ad:

```
 MobileAds.initialize(this, new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInitializationComplete(InitializationStatus initializationStatus) {}
        });
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        RewardedAd.load(this, "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917",
                adRequest, new RewardedAdLoadCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAdFailedToLoad(@NonNull LoadAdError loadAdError) {
                        // Handle the error.
                        Log.d(TAG, loadAdError.toString());
                        mRewardedAd = null;
                    }

            @Override
            public void onAdLoaded(@NonNull RewardedAd rewardedAd) {
                super.onAdLoaded(rewardedAd);
                mRewardedAd=rewardedAd;
                Log.i(TAG, "ad loaded");
                rewardedAd.setFullScreenContentCallback(new FullScreenContentCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAdClicked() {
                        super.onAdClicked();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAdDismissedFullScreenContent() {
                        super.onAdDismissedFullScreenContent();
                        mRewardedAd=null;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent(@NonNull AdError adError) {
                        super.onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent(adError);
                        Log.i(TAG, "Failed to show fullscreen ad");
                        mRewardedAd=null;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAdImpression() {
                        super.onAdImpression();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAdShowedFullScreenContent() {
                        super.onAdShowedFullScreenContent();
                    }
                });
            }
});
```

I tried putting the code inside a runOnUiThread() void because the log message says that the player was accessed on the wrong thread, but it still isn't working.